# "It's as same watch as the one I lost." - What is wrong with the sentence?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, adverbs, comparatives

Are the following sentences grammatically correct? If not, what's wrong with them?

> 1. It's as same watch as the one I lost.
> 2. It's the same watch as I lost.

Comment: Hard to elucidate what is wrong with those two though they  both sound wrong, but the following  sounds okay to me : It's the same as the watch I lost.

Comment: @k1eran It is indeed, but I've given it a go below!

Comment: @ķ̢̫̬̺͚̻͚̹̙̔̎ͣ͆͛͛, what about "It's the same watch that I lost"? Isn't that correct here too?

Answer (score 2):

> 1. It's as same watch as the one I lost.
> 2. It's the same watch as I lost.

There are two reasons that sentence one is not good. The first is grammatical, the second is semantic. When we use the degree adjective *as* in this way, the adjective it modifies must occur before a noun phrase with an indefinite article:

- *It's as good watch as the one I lost. (ungrammatical)
- It's as good **a** watch as the one I lost.

However we cannot do this with the adjective *same*:

- *It's as same a watch as the one I lost. (nonsense)

The first *as* in this sentence is a degree adverb which tells us about the degree or intensity of the following adjective. However, the adjective *same* is not gradable. It has a definite meaning which cannot come in degrees.  When we need this gradable sense of similarity, we use the word *similar*. However even when we use the adjective *similar* we need to indicate what the thing is similar *to*. If it is not indicated by the context we show this using a preposition phrase headed by *to* directly after the noun in question:

- a similar watch to that one.

Here the phrase *to that one* is the Complement of the adjective *similar* and the whole phrase is one noun phrase. In the Original Poster's *as ... as* construction the thing the OP wants to compare to is a noun phrase within a separate preposition phrase headed by the preposition *as*. This in turn is the Complement of the adverb *as*, so this won't work:

- It's as similar a watch as the one I lost.

Here we can only understand this sentence if we understand that both watches are similar to a completely different watch. So the sentence above could mean, for example:

- It's as similar a watch to my father's as the one I lost.

It cannot mean that it is similar to the one I lost.

The Original Poster therefore, needs to use sentence (2). However this sentence strongly implies that this watch actually *is* the same watch that they lost. If they just want to say that this watch and the lost watch are the same (shape, size, colour, make and so forth), they would be better off saying:

- This watch is the same as the one that I lost.